# Trim whitespaces on a String

Tags: python

How can I trim whitespaces on strings from their left and right sides?

For example,

```
___abc_d__
```

will be:

```
abc_d
```

Comment: Where did the `d` go in the first example?

Comment: How about to try to complete what you already have and come back if it doesn't work? We can't help if you don't have a specific problem.

Comment: @Ryan you're right! I did changes.

Comment: @Julien I tried many things. It doesn't work. I just need some paths, not the solution.

Comment: then show what you've tried please.

Comment: `for i in line: while line[i]` line is a string so `i` is also string, therefore you can't index it with `i`.

Comment: @Julien can you see my EDIT, please?

Answer (score 1):

Python has `lstrip` and `rstrip` methods on strings that trim whitespace from their left and right sides, respectively:

```
>>> '   abc d  '.lstrip()
'abc d  '
>>> 'abc d  '.rstrip()
'abc d'
```

Combine this with `len(s)` giving you the length of a string `s`, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Can you see my EDIT, please? It doesn't work!

Comment: @Meh: To make a literal `{` or `}` with `str.format`, double it: `${{SPACE * {0}}}`

Comment: Yes, Thank you! There is no error in syntax. The script pass but, the file, still the same, no changes...

Comment: @Meh: `line` is just a variable that holds a string. It’s not associated with the file, and assigning to it won’t change the file. Try opening a different file for writing at the same time and writing to it.

Comment: when it returns to line it count the `\n`. Can you see my EDIT2, please?

Comment: @Meh: Start with `line = line.rstrip('\n')`

Comment: Thank you, Ryan! :)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're asking but it isn't pretty.

```
>>> x = '___abc_d__'
>>> on_left = len(x) - len(x.lstrip('_'))
>>> on_right = len(x) - len(x.rstrip('_'))
>>> y = '({0}){1}({2})'.format(on_left, x.strip('_'), on_right)
>>> print(y)
(3)abc_d(2)
```

Comment: It helps so much. Thank you! But, I have a little problem on formatting, I think.

Answer (score 0):

A single regular expression would work as well. This expression captures all leading spaces, the rest of the string's content until the trailing spaces, and the trailing spaces. It then substitutes those with the length of the first group (in parentheses), the second group, and the length of the third group (in parentheses), respectively.

```
import re

def replace(s):
    return '({}){}({})'.format(len(s.group(1)), s.group(2), len(s.group(3)))
    # or, with Python 3.6 f-strings:
    # return f'({len(s.group(1))}){s.group(2)}({len(s.group(3))})'

expression = re.compile(r'^( *)(.*?)( *)$')
```

Results:

```
>>> expression.sub(replace, '   abc d  ') #  becomes (3)abc d(2)
'(3)abc d(2)'
>>> expression.sub(replace, ' abc    ') # becomes (1)abc(4)
'(1)abc(4)'
```

Note that this only replaces spaces, not all whitespace characters - use `\s` for that instead. Also, your desired output showed parentheses around the lengths, while your sample code didn't appear to be trying to do that. You can easily alter the format string in the `replace` function. Finally, the underscore character, `'_'`, is different from the space character, `' '`. I assume your actual strings have spaces, and you only used underscores to give us a visible character. Once again, you can easily change this behavior, this time by replacing `expression`'s spaces with underscores (or any character you like).

Comment: Yes, I agree! I found a solution BUT, it counts the `\n` and counts it in the second line (source code in EDIT2).